# How to use multiple button with multiple jtextField

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm newbie in Java programming.

I'm trying to test a program where there is at least four(4) JButton and there are at least three(3) JTextField. Let say Button A,B,C, and D, then Textfield 1, 2, and 3.

What I want to happen is that: when I click any of the Button. The first Textfield, let's say 1 will hold a string text. And when I click another button the second Textfield will now hold the string since 1 already holds a string text. However the tricky part is when all the textfields holds a string. When i click a button again, "textfield 1" will be overwritten from the clicked button. Then 2 and the cycle will be repeated.

```
package testing;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

 private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

}                 

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   jTextField1.setText("A");

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("B");
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("C");
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("D");
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt to solve the problem and the issue(s) you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you post the GUI you have? So we can maybe help you with logic. It seems simple at first view. `if (textField[i].getText().equals("")` then write random text into it AND `counter[i]++;` , same for all the rest, in the case none of them is empty then check for the lowest `counter[i]` and write into it and again increase it by 1

Comment: @TNT: I'm stuck. I just know how to put/set Text to a Textfield.
but anyways here is my code for a button:

"private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText("B");
}"

Then the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Please note that this code was written before the OP posted his code, but I think it will still solve the issue and therefore be worth an answer</sub>

---

I just created an example that should help you with this, it will work with any amount of buttons and textfields (except it's <= 0).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Examplerino {

    ArrayList<JTextField> tfs = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    ArrayList<JButton> bts = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    int counter = 0;

    int amountBts = 4;
    int amountTfs = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Examplerino();
            }
        });
    }

    public Examplerino() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Add new buttons to bts
        for (int i = 0; i < amountBts; i++) {
            bts.add(new JButton("b" + (i + 1)));
        }

        // Add new textfields to tfs
        for (int i = 0; i < amountTfs; i++) {
            tfs.add(new JTextField(3));
        }

        // Add buttons with action listener to the frame
        for (JButton b : bts) {
            b.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
            frame.getContentPane().add(b);
        }

        // Add textfields to frame
        for (JTextField tf : tfs) {
            tf.setEditable(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(tf);
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (counter >= tfs.size()) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            tfs.get(counter).setText(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what i wanted! :D. Now i will apply this logic and code for my program! :)

Comment: @ZeroSerum See my latest edit - Maybe that will also help you with the `setText()`.

Comment: @ZeroSerum Btw, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer that solved your issue and was the most helpful.

Comment: You latest edit is so much better! I'm really thankful!

Comment: I already accepted your answer. However I'm currently low in my reputation. So i will be counted when my reputation goes up

Comment: @ZeroSerum Glad I've helped! Upvoting is different than accepting, though. Accepting means that you press the tick so it becomes green, not the arrow that points upwards. I think accepting doesn't require any rep, but upvoting does.